# MSSQL UPDATE works but INSERT fails

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I'm on it since 2 days and can't figure it out this case.

I'm working with PHP 5.5 ans MSSQL, and it seems I can't insert in some table whereas an update works on this table and the same insert works on another table.

Of course I've check my user have the correct rights on this table.

Here's the code maybe I'm dumb...

```
// Establish connection
try {
    $pdo = new PDO(DSN, UID, PWD);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Error! ".$e->getMessage());
}

$pdo->beginTransaction();

// Merge-like event
try {
   $updateStmt->execute();
   $rows = $updateStmt->rowCount();
   if($rows == 0) {
      $insertStmt->execute();
   }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $pdo->rollBack();
    die("Error! ".$e->getMessage());
} finally {
    $insertHistoryStmt->execute();
    $pdo->commit();
}
```

All my PDO Statements objects are corrects with suitable values.
I've got no error on the INSERT seems it seems to never been executed on the DB.

Please ask if you need more code to understand I don't want to put my whole code here and say "please do my work".

Thanks I'm really stuck :/

Comment: pdo defaults to returning boolean false on failure. Unless you explicitly enable exceptions, the only one it would throw is on the initial connection attempt.  Therefore your try/catch is useless, because none of the operations you're doing in there would throw an exception in the first place.

Comment: Just configure PDO as explained [here](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#errors) to make it throw exceptions. Also note that you should re-throw an exception instead of killing the scriipt manually.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do it tomorrow in the morning I have to push an app to production tonight. Have a nice evening

Comment: OK. Thanks! The displayed error was clear I was able to correct my mistake which was "bindValues can't have the same name even if their values are the same". It don't know why it worked fine on Oracle Database and this error was only raised on MSSQL because it deals more with PDO than databases but now it works on both. I mark the question as answered with the link of the great tutorial you mentioned. Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my question's title isn't suitable now that I found the error source. But I write this answer down because it's a great tutorial which explains to debug different errors from ourselves.

If you go throw any PDO errors follow [this link](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#errors) and you will find the way.
Thank to @Your Common Sense for providing a method to learn solving errors rather than a ready to use solution.